# Render partial from sub-directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

My **views** directory is structured as follows:

view

- by domain

  - domain1

    - user_mailer

      - nav

        - _menu.html.haml
      - apply.html.haml
      - welcome.html.haml

Is there a way to render the partial from **apply.html.haml** without specifying the full path?
I read somewhere else I could do `render :partial => "./nav/menu"` but it isn't working for me.

Comment: Have you tried _render :partial => "nav/menu"_ without the dot and the first slash?

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well and it did not work. After much looking around finding no answer I just resorted to using the full path.

Answer (score 8):

Use the full path in the render method.

For example, if you have the following directory structure ...

app
| views
|--» landing
|----» main_template.html.erb
|----» desktop
|------» _home.html.erb
|----»  mobile
|------» _home.html.erb

... and `main_template` which calls render is found under`app/views/landing`, then calls to *render*  would look like this ... 
`render partial: 'landing/desktop/home'` 
 
`render partial: 'landing/mobile/home'`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's currently possible based on [these](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1143) [github](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6478) threads.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `append_view_path` in your controller. I use it like that:

```
class DemoController < SiteController
.
.
    before_filter do
        append_view_path Rails.root.join("domain/domain1/user_mailer")
    end 
...
```

Of course this only works if you have different view/partial names in these directories.